# java.lang.NullPointerException Android 4.2

Tags: java, android

Error java.lang.NullPointerException only in Android 4.2
App crash only in android 4.2, for android 4.0 works well
In Eclipse with emulator 4.2 not the error in logcat but in google play developer yes
sorry for my english, thank for help me

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2565)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2820)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5162)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:5145)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:359)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:309)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3535)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3717)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Activity

```
public class directo extends Activity
{
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private WebView webview2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.directo);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container1);
        showVideo1();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webview2.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webview2.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        webview2.onPause();
        super.onDestroy();

    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void showVideo1(){
        webview2 = new WebView(this);

        webview2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview2.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview2.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview2.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());
        webview2.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webview2.setWebChromeClient( new FullscreenableChromeClient(this));
        webview2.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.766.0 Safari/534.36");


        webview2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1f));



            String js = "<iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"http://veetle.com/index.php/mobile/channel/4d09f6339bb0b\" frameborder=\"0\">\n" +
                    "</iframe>\n" +
                    "";
            webview2.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://fake.com", js,
                    "text/html", "UTF-8", null);


        ll.addView(webview2, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    private class mWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {

         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
             finish();
             return true;
            }
         return false;
    }
    public void recargar(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, directo.class);
        //intent.putExtra("someData", "Here is some data");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
    public void volver(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, inicio1.class);
        //intent.putExtra("someData", "Here is some data");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_set_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="volver"
        android:text="@string/volver" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_set_time"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="recargar"
        android:text="@string/recargar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat

```
08-15 20:02:27.899: W/ActivityThread(1062): Application com.futbolespanoltv.android is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
08-15 20:02:27.968: I/System.out(1062): Sending WAIT chunk
08-15 20:02:27.978: I/dalvikvm(1062): Debugger is active
08-15 20:02:28.168: I/System.out(1062): Debugger has connected
08-15 20:02:28.168: I/System.out(1062): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-15 20:02:28.368: I/System.out(1062): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-15 20:02:28.568: I/System.out(1062): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-15 20:02:28.778: I/System.out(1062): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-15 20:02:28.978: I/System.out(1062): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-15 20:02:29.178: I/System.out(1062): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-15 20:02:29.378: I/System.out(1062): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-15 20:02:29.640: I/System.out(1062): debugger has settled (1303)
08-15 20:02:31.428: D/dalvikvm(1062): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 204K, 12% free 2490K/2816K, paused 130ms, total 142ms
08-15 20:02:31.458: I/dalvikvm-heap(1062): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.588MB for 2141456-byte allocation
08-15 20:02:31.608: D/dalvikvm(1062): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 4579K/4908K, paused 148ms, total 148ms
08-15 20:02:31.708: D/dalvikvm(1062): GC_CONCURRENT freed 9K, 7% free 4581K/4908K, paused 17ms+6ms, total 100ms
08-15 20:02:32.058: D/dalvikvm(1062): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 7% free 4584K/4908K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-15 20:02:32.118: I/dalvikvm-heap(1062): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.187MB for 4818256-byte allocation
08-15 20:02:32.308: D/dalvikvm(1062): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 9289K/9616K, paused 95ms+16ms, total 190ms
08-15 20:02:32.308: D/dalvikvm(1062): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 96ms
08-15 20:02:32.838: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:33.089: D/gralloc_goldfish(1062): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-15 20:02:39.738: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:41.749: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 414 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:42.149: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:42.779: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:43.259: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:47.868: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:54.378: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:54.438: D/TilesManager(1062): Starting TG #0, 0x2a509088
08-15 20:02:55.278: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:02:59.739: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:03:01.718: D/dalvikvm(1062): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2426K, 24% free 8492K/11040K, paused 103ms, total 128ms
08-15 20:03:02.139: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 398 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:03:02.929: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:03:03.569: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:03:04.989: I/Choreographer(1062): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 20:03:07.449: E/Web Console(1062): Uncaught Url::appStore app does not exist on platform at http://veetle.com/minified/ff46d3264790eff826475edd292e3fc8_minified.js:194
08-15 20:03:07.768: E/Web Console(1062): Url::appChannel app does not exist on platform at http://veetle.com/minified/ff46d3264790eff826475edd292e3fc8_minified.js:343
08-15 20:03:08.268: D/libEGL(1062): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
08-15 20:03:08.278: D/libEGL(1062): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
08-15 20:03:08.308: E/Web Console(1062): Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL fake://fake.com from frame with URL http://veetle.com/index.php/mobile/channel/5208af0563c2d. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
08-15 20:03:08.308: E/Web Console(1062):  at null:1
08-15 20:03:08.658: I/OMXClient(1062): Using client-side OMX mux.
08-15 20:03:08.718: E/Web Console(1062): Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL fake://fake.com from frame with URL http://veetle.com/index.php/mobile/channel/5208af0563c2d. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
08-15 20:03:08.718: E/Web Console(1062):  at null:1
```

Comment: I think you cut off the top of the error

Comment: Can you give us more information? A full LogCat would be helpful, like krsteeve mentioned and also, when is it crashing? When you press a button? When you launch the application? More details please.

Comment: Try to move your super call (super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);) to top of requestWindowFeature

Comment: Crash when i press tabhost in main activity

Comment: Logcat in first post
Thank

Comment: when my streaming is live This closed
When my streaming is off, this error not happen